# Probability with Martingales Algebras and $pi$-systems

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

I am studying the book Probability with Martingales by D Williams and I am confused with section 1.7. In this section, Williams introduces Caratheodory's Extension theorem. Here he states,

> Let S be a set, Let $\Sigma_0$ be an algebra on S, and let $$\Sigma := \sigma(\Sigma_0).$$ If $\mu_0$ is a countably additive map $\mu_0 : \Sigma_0 \to [0,\infty]$, then there exists a measure $\mu$ on $(S,\Sigma)$ such that $$\mu=\mu_0$$ on $\Sigma_0$. If $\mu_0 < \infty$, then, by Lemma 1.6, this extension is unique - an algebra is a $\pi$-system!

I do not understand the conclusion of the theorem, is it not always the case that an algebra is a $\pi$-system? An algebra is closed under finite intersections and this perfectly matches the definition of a $\pi$-system. Why is the conclusion to the theorem so surprising as to warrant an exclamation?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the exclamation is concerned, I think all one can say is that Williams is a...colorful writer (sometimes to his detriment, IMHO).

The bit about an algebra being a $\pi$ system is not part of the *conclusion* of the result (since, as you point out, this is trivially true by the definitions), but rather part of the result's *proof*. Using Lemma 1.6 (which is about $\pi$ systems) and the fact that an algebra is a $\pi$ system, one can conclude the stated uniqueness result.